# How does gmapping uses odometry data (from the encoder + IMU)

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm currently working on a robotics project which uses gmapping. If I'm not wrong, the gmapping uses information from odometry and laser to obtain more accurate results. But how does the IMU and encoder data is used in this case? Any help is appreciated :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67153/how-does-gmapping-uses-odometry-data-(from-the-encoder-+-imu)/) by [Andrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5397/andrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IMU + encoder are usually fused into a combined improved odometry estimate (e.g. by the robot_pose_ekf node) that is in turn put into gmapping (instead of raw odometry).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using robot pose ekf, it fuses the imu and encoder data into odom. This is a combination of both the inputs. Gmapping uses that combined odom as an initial guess and then relies on scan registration.

---

Originally posted by [musiqsoulchild](https://answers.ros.org/users/21484/musiqsoulchild/) with karma: 53 on 2015-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2